# C++ %f dot instead of comma

Tags: c++, locale

I'm reading a file in **c++** where floating point numbers (%f) have a dot instead of comma.

Each line in the file has 3 numbers like that

```
1.000 -1.000 0.000
```

for example.

My app does not want to read the number past the dot, so If I do

```
fscanf(file, "%f %f %f\n", &x, &y, &z );
```

for example x is set to 1, everything else is left on 0 because it only reads to the first dot.

I've already read somewhere that I should change the locale using **setlocale** or something similar but it didn't work out.

Could someone please explain how to do it properly or if there is another way?

---

**EDIT:**
I removed "QT" from the title. First it was there because I thought that maybe QT has some special settings or something for locales. It's weird that my **ST3** default `C++ Single File` build system has the locale already set to use dots instead of commas, but I had to set it in QT. Does every compiler have their own default locale setting?

Comment: "it didn't work out", what exactly did you try? Fact is, it works, provided you do it right. Please provide a minimal example while you're at it. Oh, and please explain how Qt (did you mean that with "QT"?) is related to your question.

Comment: If you use fscanf, then that's not QT.

Comment: Question doesn't seem to have anything to do with C++ or Qt.

Comment: The thing why I added QT in the name is because if I try the same example and compile it with the default "C++  Single File" build system in Sublime Text 3 it works with the dots but doesn't work with the commas. Its weird and I'm not even setting any locales.

Comment: Hmm, just noticed this is `scanf` not `printf`. Same solution, but a better dupe target would be [How do i read a float value when this value have comma instead of dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007872/how-do-i-read-a-float-value-when-this-value-have-comma-instead-of-dot) or [How to parse numbers like "3.14" with scanf when locale expects "3,14"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919817/how-to-parse-numbers-like-3-14-with-scanf-when-locale-expects-3-14).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the line

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");
```

before the call to `fscanf`. Make sure to add

```
#include <locale.h>
```

to be able to call `setlocale`.

More on setlocale can be seen at http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale.

Comment: I was adding the line to the wrong spot in my code and instead of `LC_ALL` I had `LC_NUMERIC`. I had it in the `main.cpp` file instead of the actual function where I use `fscanf`. Thank you.