# How can i get arbitrary number of floats from input in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, scanf

I am making a sparse matrix calculator, and the data that each cell are going to hold are floats.

My dumass, in a first scenario, thought it would be all ints (do not read the homework documentation fast, ma' friends). So then a made this line of code

`scanf("%f%c", &number, &spacing);`

And i used `spacing` as a condition to stop reading input. If `spacing` was ' ', i would keep reading. However, if it was '\n', i would understand that the user ended the current matrix line.

Then i discovered that no, it will not be just ints, there will be some floats. Ir order to adapt my program, i just had to change the type in structures and some function returns.

But now i am with this problem: because of the `%f%c`, if i insert '1 1 1,3 1', my program will create FIVE columns, because it thinks that `,` is a separator.

How can i change my scanf in order to make it to parse the `,` as part of an decimal, and ' ' as spacing. Should i use RegEx?

Here is the function code

```
Row *createRow(int rowNum)
{
    Row *newRow = mallocRow(rowNum);
    float number = 0.0;
    int col = 0;
    char spacing = ' ';

    do
    {
        scanf("%f%c", &number, &spacing);
        if (number != 0.0)
        {
            appendNode(
                newRow,
                createNode(newRow->row, col, number)
            );
        }
        else
        {
            newRow->size++;
        }
        col++;
    } while (spacing != '\n');

    return newRow;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? `%f` is matching a single float. If you need arbitrary number of these, use a loop.

Comment: Yes i am inside a loop, but the stop condition is if '%c' returns a newline '\n'. But with floats,  the '.' or ',' goes inside the char var, and then i  cannot read the float

Comment: I added the entire function code :)

Comment: Related is setting the locale in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20009835/4142924) to [How do i read a float value when this value have comma instead of dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007872/how-do-i-read-a-float-value-when-this-value-have-comma-instead-of-dot)

Comment: Note that MS VC has a version of [`scanf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-scanf-l-wscanf-wscanf-l?view=msvc-170) which considers a locale. `int _scanf_l(const char *format, _locale_t locale [, argument]... );`

Comment: One way, would be to read each field with `%s` and replace every occurrence of `','` with `'.'` then apply `sscanf`.

Comment: @WeatherVane it worked!!! The locale thing. And i do not understand why my ubuntu was getting ',' as decimal separator. I am brazilian but my OS, everything, is set to english. Just keyboard alyout is different. But thanks!!

And guys, would you mind to add your solutions as answers so then i can vote them? And thanks for the attention!!!!!

Comment: I suggest you upvote the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20009835/4142924) from @chux-ReinstateMonica which I linked as it was a previous question.

Comment: Or [scanf unknown number of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52937192/2410359) to cope with the unknown number of `float` in a line.

Comment: JoãoPedroMartinsdePaula, Does "get arbitrary number of floats from input ?" have a sane upper bound for the number of float like maybe 1000 or less?